C runtime LLVM error: error while loading shared libraries
I am trying to write my first ever compiler in C using LLVM for its backend, but I get an error when I try to run it. I have not found anything about this exact error message on other places.
Here is the error message:
./build/cave: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVMWindowsManifest.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The latest LLVM is installed from source, I ran make, and make install too.
OS: WSL Debian 12
Makefile:
CC := clang
PROJECT := cave
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic
# LLVM stuff
CFLAGS += `llvm-config --cflags`
LDFLAGS := `llvm-config --ldflags`
LIBS := `llvm-config --libs`

INCLUDES := -Iinclude
SRC_DIR := src
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
BUILD_DIR := build
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
.PHONY: all build clean

all: build

build: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDES) $(BUILD_ARGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(BUILD_ARGS)

release:
    $(MAKE) BUILD_ARGS="-O3" -B

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

codegen.h:
#pragma once

#include <llvm-c/Types.h>

typedef struct LLVMBackend {
    LLVMContextRef context;
    LLVMModuleRef module;
    LLVMBuilderRef builder;

    LLVMValueRef *(*generateLLVMIR)(struct LLVMBackend *);
} LLVMBackend;

LLVMBackend backend_new(void);
void free_backend(LLVMBackend);

Here is the codegen.c file too:
#include "codegen.h"

#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <stddef.h>

static LLVMValueRef *generateLLVMIR(LLVMBackend *self) {
    (void)self; // not used yet
    return NULL;
}

LLVMBackend backend_new(void) {
    LLVMContextRef context = LLVMContextCreate();
    LLVMModuleRef module =
        LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("example", context);
    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(context);
    return (LLVMBackend){
        .context = context,
        .module = module,
        .builder = builder,

        .generateLLVMIR = generateLLVMIR,
    };
}

void free_backend(LLVMBackend backend) {
    LLVMDisposeBuilder(backend.builder);
    LLVMDisposeModule(backend.module);
    LLVMContextDispose(backend.context);
}

I tried reinstalling the LLVM binaries with make clean and then make and make install again, but it didn't work.

You need to specify path where your executable can find LLVM libs at runtime:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(llvm-config --libdir):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./build/cave

